# Java Loops and Random numbers

Tags: java

Hi I am having some problems with using random numbers inside of loops.

```
 private void SetMines()
    {
        Random randRowGen = new Random();
        Random randColGen = new Random();
        int mineCount = 0;
        int numMines = (ROWS * COLUMNS)* (int)0.156;
        while(mineCount <= numMines)
        {
            int randRow = randRowGen.nextInt(ROWS)+1;
            int randCol = randColGen.nextInt(COLUMNS)+1;
            grid[randRow][randCol] = new Character('*');
            mineCount++;
        }

    }
```

Here is my method it is going through an array size 25 * 25 and picking random spots and putting "mines" there. The only problem is it only selects one location to put a "mine" in and it needs to put 97 mines in random spots.

Any help will be appreciated thanks!!

Comment: unclear what you are asking, but I would like you to check the value of `int numMines = (ROWS * COLUMNS)* (int)0.156;`

Comment: What is the result of `(ROWS * COLUMNS)* (int)0.156;`?

Comment: What is the result of `(int) 0.156`?

Comment: You need to select 97 distinct random **cells** to place the mines. Right now, even if you were looping 97 times, that wouldn't guarantee that you would have placed mines at 97 distinct cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't Random, it's `int numMines = (ROWS * COLUMNS)* (int)0.156;`.  Have you checked what that value is?  It's 0, because (int) 0.156 equals 0.

Perhaps you want `int numMines = (int) ((double) 0.156 * ROWS * COLUMNS);`.  The problem with integer maths is that you can lose a LOT of precision.

Comment: @alfasin `(int)0.156` is pretty damn close to zero ain't it.

Comment: @user2310289 Try this: `System.out.println((int)0.156);`

Comment: Yep.  Reworded to point out that I meant that the problem was the rounding.

Comment: @alfasin I am actually agreeing with you.

Comment: It turned out to be zero because (int)0.156 = 0

Comment: I just changed the variable type to double and then inside of the while loop condition I cast the numMines as an int

Answer (score 4):

Your `numMines` calculation will always return `0`, because when you cast a `double` that is less than `1` to an `int`, it will be set to `0`, which means that the statement in your while loop will only be run a single time, hence only a single mine being placed.

Answer (score 0):

Make your computer suffer and make it drop all those mines.

Remember. The definition of "computation" is "to force a machine do a boring job that nobody else would like to do" :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rows = 25;
    int cols = 25;

    boolean[][] mines = new boolean[rows][cols];

    while(mineCount(mines) < 97){
        dropMine(mines);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            System.out.print("[");
            if (mines[i][j]){
                System.out.print("*");
            }else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("] ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}

private static void dropMine(boolean[][] mines) {
    int x = (int)(Math.random()*25);
    int y = (int)(Math.random()*25);
    mines[x][y] = true;
}

private static int mineCount(boolean[][] mines) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<25;j++){
            if (mines[i][j]){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```